# Is it possible to inject a script into a HTML response through Akamai?

Tags: cdn, akamai

This is a bit of an edge use case, but I want to inject some JavaScript into a page without making a code change at the back end. So I'm wondering if there is a rule I can set for a specific route at Akamai, that would inject or add a `<script>` tag into the HTML body. I could host the external JavaScript file, but I just don't want to have to make a change at the origin to the HTML response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Akamai, HTML content can be modified with the use of EdgeWorkers.  For example, the [find-replace-stream example](https://github.com/akamai/edgeworkers-examples/tree/master/edgecompute/examples/stream/find-replace-stream) can be modified to inject a `<script>` tag at the end of the  tag.

```js
export function responseProvider(request) {
  // Get text to be searched for and new replacement text from Property Manager variables in the request object.
  const tosearchfor = '</head>';
  const newtext = request.getVariable('<script>......</script></head>');
  // Must have a number larger than 0 to allow and limit replacements counts
  const howManyReplacements = 1;

  return httpRequest(`${request.scheme}://${request.host}${request.url}`).then(response => {
    return createResponse(
      response.status,
      getSafeResponseHeaders(response.getHeaders()),
      response.body
      .pipeThrough(new TextDecoderStream())
      .pipeThrough(new FindAndReplaceStream(tosearchfor, newtext, howManyReplacements))
      .pipeThrough(new TextEncoderStream())
    );
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this sort of thing can be done with [EdgeWorkers](https://developer.akamai.com/akamai-edgeworkers-overview).